# Why I need to specify AuthenticationSchemes although I have set the defaultScheme?

Tags: jwt, .net-6.0

I'm developing a Web-Api in .NET 6, and I'm trying to use JWT for authentication.

In my `Program.cs` file, I've added the authentication as follows:

```
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(defaultScheme: JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options => options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:SigningKey"])),
    });
```

and I'm using the `[Authorize]` attribute on the methods I want to protect.

This works only if I specify the authentication scheme like this:
`[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`

What am I doing wrong setting up the default authentication scheme so I can use the `[Authorize]` attribute as is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!

You need to add app.UseAuthentication() in program.cs because there is no authentication middleware now.